# spark orc read throws when using native orc impl "java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, orc

spark native orc reader is not working as expected. please find below details

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoders, SparkSession}
case class GateDoc(var xml: Array[Byte], var cknid: String = null)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.impl","native")
import spark.implicits._
val df = spark.read.schema(Encoders.product[GateDoc].schema).orc(inputFile).as[GateDoc] // problem here while reading throws below mentioned exception
df.write.orc(op)
```

throws

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$BytesColumnVectorUtil.commonReadByteArrays(TreeReaderFactory.java:1506)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$BytesColumnVectorUtil.readOrcByteArrays(TreeReaderFactory.java:1528)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$BinaryTreeReader.nextVector(TreeReaderFactory.java:878)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.nextBatch(TreeReaderFactory.java:2012)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.RecordReaderImpl.nextBatch(RecordReaderImpl.java:1284)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextBatch(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.orc.OrcColumnarBatchReader.nextKeyValue(OrcColumnarBatchReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.scan_nextBatch_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However,  It works well when using spark.sql.orc.impl = hive

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoders, SparkSession}
    case class GateDoc(var xml: Array[Byte], var cknid: String = null)
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.impl","hive")
    import spark.implicits._
    val df = spark.read.schema(Encoders.product[GateDoc].schema).orc(inputFile).as[GateDoc]
    df.write.orc(op)
```

I'm well aware why java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException is throw in my usecase but why it is initializing my case class array type field with negative value?

I have also checked a few partitions metadata as below

```
java -jar/usr/lib/spark/jars/orc-tools-1.5.5-uber.jar data part-00.snappy.orc
  java -jar /usr/lib/spark/jars/orc-tools-1.5.5-uber.jar meta part-00.snappy.orc
```

which seems to be ok

More Details about Environment :

```
 Scala version 2.11.12
 Spark Version 2.4.4
 Orc Version 1.5.5
 EMR emr-5.29.0
```

Please help me out. I feel there is some bug in orc native reader.

Comment: Can you share some of your data so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @kfkhalili i cannot share data ... i have provided the schema in input... data is too huge aroung 1.1TB snappy compressed ... it is not clearly known in the log for which partition it is failing to deserialize ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how these ORC files are created, since the purpose of the setting you're changing is to account for differences in how the data was written https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-orc.html

Comment: @mazaneicha Input data was created by upstream spark jobs which were using orc.impl=native and case class GateDoc xml field is set as (doc.toXml().getBytes("UTF-8")) ..... here doc field is GATE(https://gate.ac.uk/) Document which was generated by HtmlContent.